# Figuring out if variable is instanceof a prototype of a function

Tags: javascript

Say I have

```
function Foo() {
    // stuff
} 

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    return new Bar();
}

function Bar() {};

module.exports = Foo;
```

Now say I have

```
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo instanceof Foo); // true

const bar = new Foo().bar();
console.log(bar instanceof Foo); // false
console.log(bar instanceof Foo.prototype.bar); // false
```

Here `Bar` is never exported. So how can I test if `bar` is an instance of ... something? Can I somehow have `bar instanceof Foo` or a subset of Foo or something?

Comment: @apsillers yes good catch. Fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the function `Bar` is available as the `constructor` on `Bar.prototype`, which is in `new Bar()`'s prototype chain. (This is basically the only thing that `constructor` is ever useful for in practice.)

```
bar instanceof new Foo().bar().constructor
```

Conversely, if you *don't* want to leak the `Bar` constructor function in this fashion, you can clobber `Bar.prototype.constructor` with a new value (or just `delete` it) before your export `Foo`. If `constructor` has been cleared in this way, you can still check if an object's prototype chain includes the same prototype as a newly-created `Bar` instance:

```
var barProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(new Foo().bar());
var isBar = barProto.isPrototypeOf(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the prototype of one bar to another:

```
 Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) === Object.getPrototypeOf((new Foo).bar())
```